# Upload and Check-in File to SharePoint from a Remote Machine

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to upload and check-in files to a SharePoint Intranet site using Powershell. This script will be run on a remote machine, NOT the server hosting the site. Uploading the files was relatively easy following the [instructions given here](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=487).

Below is a small section of the process I am using to upload the files. They are successfully uploaded but remained checked out to me. Is there anyway to check these files in using Powershell?

```
$destination = "http://mycompanysite.com/uploadhere/Docs” 
$File = get-childitem “C:\Docs\stuff\To Upload.txt”

# Upload the file 
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$webclient.UploadFile($destination + "/" + $File.Name, "PUT", $File.FullName)
```

Unfortunately using the SharePoint PowerShell module won't work since this is run on a remote machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have an easier time using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client instead which you can download from here: [Download SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" #loads sharepoint client runtime
$destination = "http://mycompanysite.com/uploadhere"
$listName = "Docs"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($destination)
$context.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials #signs you in as the currently logged in user on the local host
$context.RequestTimeout = 10000000
$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$context.Load($list)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$stream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$fileOptions = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$fileOptions.Overwrite = $true
$fileOptions.ContentStream = $stream
$fileOptions.URL = $File
$upload = $list.RootFolder.Files.Add($fileOptions)
$context.Load($upload)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$upload.CheckIn("My check in message", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn) #other options can be looked at here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.checkintype.aspx
$context.ExecuteQuery() #finally save your checkin
```

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner. This is exactly the solution I ended up using. For some reason using REST/oData I kept running into permissions issues.